# Select any item from select using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara

I'm trying to write a test for a little Rails app I'm working on. The Users model has a has_many through relationship (both ways) with other users and users have a has_many relationship with assignments. On the UI end of things, users can choose another user to attach new assignments to. I'd like to be able to test this. The problem right now, is that I can't figure out how to use Capybara to select from a list of items that I don't know the text to. I wrote a rake task to generate my test database randomly, and while I could look in the database and write my test that way, it would of course break the second I reset the database.

I'm only testing that the number of assignments in the test database changes by 1. I'm using Rspec with Capybara.

Comment: Look at the source of [select](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method). It will be easy for you to write code that will select random value from `select` after that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Say the `<select>` element has id "foo". Then the following should work.

```
option = first('#foo option').text
select option, from: 'foo'
```

Answer (score 16):

You can find the option element, and then call `select_option` on it. For example, to select the third element in a drop down:

```
all('#foo option')[2].select_option
```

Comment: I used sample to pick random option.    all('#foo option').sample.select_option

Comment: @VenkateshNannan How do you deal with a blank/prompt option ? (`<option value="">Please select</option>`)

Comment: When(/^I select first option on dropdown "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|
 select all("##{arg1} option")[1].text, from: arg1
end

Comment: Thank you all, what is the significance of the hash # in  '#foo option' ?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon It's a CSS selector for an element with `id="foo"`